# Node.js - i want to get var 'hash' out of function

Tags: node.js

**hash.js**

```
 var crypto = require('crypto'),
  fs = require('fs')

var algorithm = 'sha256',
   shasum = crypto.createHash(algorithm)

// Updating shasum with file content
var filename = __dirname + "/hufs.png",
  s = fs.ReadStream(filename)
s.on('data', function(data) {
  shasum.update(data)
})

// making digest
s.on('end', function() {
  var hash = shasum.digest('hex') // this var
  console.log(hash + '  ' + filename)
})
```

I have a this code, then I want to call a var 'hash' out of function

i don't know what to do, i want fixed code

i need your helps

Comment: `hash` is in the local scope. Place `var hash = null` outside the scope, and edit `var hash` to `hash`. That should allow you to use the value of `hash` outside the function `onEnd`. If that is not what you want, please provide examples of what you want and rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the result of your hash you must get the value after the "end" Event is triggerd and if you did same code like this

```
var hash;
s.on('end', function() {
  hash = shasum.digest('hex') // this var
  console.log(hash + '  ' + filename)
})
console.log(hash);
```

Your hash will be "undefined" because after the event is trigger your "console.log(hash)" will have been executed

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
  fs = require('fs')

var algorithm = 'sha256',
   shasum = crypto.createHash(algorithm)

// Updating shasum with file content
var filename = __dirname + "/3.png",
    s = fs.ReadStream(filename)

s.on('data', function(data) {
  shasum.update(data)
})

// making digest
var hash;
s.on('end', function() {
  hash = shasum.digest('hex') // this var
  console.log(hash + '  ' + filename)
})
// Here I simulate some code that will be executed after the "end" event was trigger
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(hash);
},5000);
```